# Why using curl | sudo sh is not advised?

Tags: curl, sudo

While I was reading the [introduction to the Rust programming language](https://wayback.archive.org/web/20150426140301/http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/installing-rust.html), I came across the installation method which asks to use the following command

```
curl -sf -L https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup.sh | sudo sh
```

with a note of caution that this is not the most trusted way of installing an application. Can anybody provide me the details about how this command can be dangerous and are there any methods to protect yourself from its effects?

Comment: `curl` goes to an untrusted site on the internet and returns text.  You pipe that text into a shell with root access on your local box.  So the person you don't trust is able to run arbitrary code on your machine.  The security implications are, I hope, fairly obvious.

Comment: Can i just run sh command with a destination directory so that sudo is not required.

Comment: I would strongly recommend dumping the output to a file and examining it.

Comment: [the Rust programming language book](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/installing-rust.html) has a link to a [blog post on using curl to install](http://blog.emillon.org/posts/2014-12-27-on-the-curl-sh-pattern.html).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because you are giving root access to whatever script you are executing. It can do a wide variety of nasty things.

If Rust site is ever compromised and that script gets a tiny piece that installs malware silently, you wouldn't know, without inspecting the script first.

Comment: Exactly. The curl | sh pattern can be challenging to defend—even if you're not giving it root access, the contents of your user account are valuable too. If you can use a tool that checks integrity instead of just the transport (HTTPS), that's even better. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/12/12/security-spectrum-curl-sh/?utm_source=stackoverflow-ao&utm_campaign=security-spectrum-curl-sh&utm_medium=referral

Comment: assuming you use HTTPS: you merely have to trust the domain. this is exactly as secure like every time you ever downloaded a installer manually. i.e. almost every time a Windows or OS X user ever installed software.

Comment: @flyingsheep When you do that, you can check the certificate in the browser, is it still the same?

Answer (score 14):

As Daniel said plus few more reasons:

- if the script were provided to you over HTTP instead HTTPS, Man In The Middle attack can be performed by some evil 3rd Party. Using HTTPS you have at least confidence, that the script will be downloaded as-is from the site
- if the connection closes mid-stream, there may be executed partial commands, which were not intended to (and potentially dangerous). (see 1st link)
- you may also think that opening script in the browser to check if it's not evil will mitigate the risk. Unfortunately it will not, because site owner may show different content for browser User-Agents (see 2nd link)

How to properly mitigate risk then:

#### Ideally:

> Use this approach when making changes on production server

```
curl -sf -L https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup.sh -o rustup.sh
less rustup.sh
chmod +x rustup.sh
sudo ./rustup.sh
```

#### Significantly better, but not perfect (but one-liner):

> You can use this approach on dev machine / test server

```
su -c "curl https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup.sh -o rustup.sh && chmod +x rustup.sh && ./rustup.sh"
```

### References:

- https://www.seancassidy.me/dont-pipe-to-your-shell.html
- https://jordaneldredge.com/blog/one-way-curl-pipe-sh-install-scripts-can-be-dangerous/

Comment: You can proof your scripts against partial execution by putting the whole thing into the body of a function, and executing that function on the last line. If you know a script is defined like that, it’s exactly as secure as downloading and then executing some installer.