# How to run (./) a bash script located in the cloud?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, execution

Using a ubuntu 16.04 what I do is :

1. Download the `.sh` script using `wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/...`
2. Turn the `.sh` file executable `sudo chmod guo+x sysInit.sh`
3. Execute the code through `sudo ./sysInit.sh`

I was wondering if it is possible to run the code directly from the web.
Would be something like: `sudo ./ https://gist.githubusercontent.com/...`.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cUrl to download and run your script. I don't think its installed by default on Ubuntu so you'll have to `sudo apt-get install curl` first if you want to use it. To download and run your script with sudo just run

```
curl -sL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/blah.sh | sudo sh
```

Be warned this is very risky and not advised for security reasons. See this related question [why-using-curl-sudo-sh-is-not-advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382739/why-using-curl-sudo-sh-is-not-advised)

Comment: | sudo must be used!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible using `curl` and piping the result to `sh`.

Try the following command.

`curl https://url-to-your-script-file/scriptFile.sh | sh`

Answer (score 0):

No, sudo only works from a command line prompt in a shell