# How the alternatives are better than using curl | sudo sh

Tags: bash, shell, security, curl, pipe

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382739/why-using-curl-sudo-sh-is-not-advised) page says of the "using curl | sudo sh" pattern to:

> Use this approach when making changes on production server [instead]
>
> ```
> curl -sf -L https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup.sh -o rustup.sh
> less rustup.sh
> chmod +x rustup.sh
> sudo ./rustup.sh
> ```

I don't see why this is any better than just doing `curl | sudo sh`. What difference does it make that you downloaded the file and chmod'd it first. I haven't seen any arguments what the alternatives are to curl | sh and why they are better, only the problems with curl | sh. Please explain how something like the above is better (in some detail), or any other alternative is better in some detail.

For example, none of the responses [here](https://gist.github.com/btm/6700524) explain any alternatives or why they are better. Same with every other website I've seen.

The main argument is that if someone hacks your server they could replace the code with something else. But couldn't this happen with any package manager? I mean who deeply checks the code before `npm installing` something every time, even a native C extension with it. Those could be doing the same things, especially with before/after shell scripts running on install. I don't see how these are any safer than just piping in bash.

Comment: because using `less` you can inspect the script instead of running it blindly with `sudo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The significant difference is the use of **`less`**. The quote prompts you to check the contents of the file you have downloaded. This is necessary, because the code is not signed. A package manager uses signatures to trust the sources. It is important to check the contents, because it is not secure to pipe something from a web server directly into your shell. See [here](https://github.com/sethgrid/exploit) how to exploit it [here](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2016/04/detecting-curl-pipe-bash-server-side/) for a description.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.idontplaydarts.com/images/bashmov.gif

shell-redirection can apparently be detected at the server side, and a normal script can be delivered upon normal inspection and a malicious payload be delivered upon sh redirection, so at least you'll avoid that issue, this website explains it much better than i can: https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2016/04/detecting-curl-pipe-bash-server-side/